# Python Spark: Write certain columns of an RDD to text file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to write certain columns of an RDD to a text file. 
Currently I am using pandas to do it.

`df_2016_pandas = df_2016.select('id', 'source', 'date', 'title', 'abstract', 'content').toPandas()`

and then converting the column to string to write to text file

`title_string = ''.join(df_2016_pandas.title.tolist())`

`output_file.write(title_string)`

In this way, I am writing `content` and `abstract` to the same text file.(I want mt text file to be comprised of `title`, `content` and `abstract` from the RDD).

Since the data is huge(28M records), I reckon it is inefficient to use pandas.
Is there a way I can do it in spark(python) i.e., write certain columns(tuples) of an RDD to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Question is too much clear but from explanation looks like you need only selected column to be in output file. PySpark and Pandas integration is not preferable. You can save df directly using below. This will store data in partitions, then  you concatenate files and download from HDFS.

```
#Tested on pyspark 1.6 
df_2016.select('title', 'abstract', 'content').write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").save("name_file")
```